# Ubuntu 12.04 on Bangho

Tags: 12.04

This question is (mostly) for people in Argentina. ¿Have anyone tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 on a Bangho notebook (with i3-560 processor)? I haven't found any experiences online with this brand. The specs of the sistem are below (in spanish):

Procesador Intel Corei3 Serie 2300
Memoria 4Gb. DDR3. - Disco Rígido SATA 500Gb.
Chipset Intel HM65
Video Intel HM65 configurable hasta 1748MB
Placa de red 10/100/1000, Wireless 802.11b/g/n
Bluetooth Pantalla 15.6" HD (1366 x 768) - Peso 2,3Kg.

Best regards,
Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brief commentary of my experience on installing Ubuntu 12.04 in a Bangho Futura 1500 i3-560 notebook.

First of all, after installation the system works fine and fast. No popups telling you that something has gone wrong or asking you to send a report to the development team, or just informing that Unity has closed unexpectedly... again. Intel HM65 video card seems to work fine and doesn't requiere additional drivers. The same goes for the soundcard.

Then: components such as mousepad, bluetooth, webcam, wifi & keyboard special keys works out-of-the-box.

Some hardware sepcs:

Processor: Intel Corei3 Serie 2300
RAM: 4Gb. DDR3.
HD: SATA 500Gb.
Chipset: Intel HM65
Video: Intel HM65 (up to 1748MB)
Network: 10/100/1000, Wireless 802.11b/g/n